# RelativeLayout is not autosizing when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

RelativeLayout is not autosizable when keyboard is shown:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:fontFamily="Courier New" />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When keyboard is shown elements not autosizes:
[image: When keyboard is hidden]

[image: When keyboard is shown]

When keyboard is shown, content is beyond of top of phone

Comment: What is your desired result? Static layout, but the EditText slides up with the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

add this property to your root layout(Relative layout):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and also add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to activity tag in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** to your manifest:

```
  <activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
  </activity>
```